# how to disable a nosetest plugin

Tags: python, nose, nosetests

I don't want a coverage report so I uninstalled 'pip uninstall coverage' plugin.  However I still get an error saying:

```
nose.plugins.cover: ERROR: Coverage not available: unable to import coverage module
```

How do I disable the calling of this plugin, or any other plugin for that matter.  Is there a list of enabled plugins that I can edit, or some api I can call to disable it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `~/.noserc` file, it is likely, you have there entries related to uninstalled plugin.

I am able to reproduce your problem if I have in the `~/.noserc`:

```
[nosetests]
with-coverage=1
```

but it happens also, if I have there

```
[nosetests]
with-coverage=0
```

If I remove it, the problem is resolved.

The file can be also located in your working directory.

Comment: I didn't have that file either in my home or working dir.  I added to my homedir with nothing in it and it still complained. :(

Comment: @ftravers There is some info at [nose doc](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html). Quick test cold be done with setting up environmental variable `NOSE_IGNORE_CONFIG_FILES`.